# Best way to access client side devices from a web application

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, activex

I need to provide support for various scanners and printers to an Intranet web application. Basically the user needs to be able to take pictures using his webcam or camera, scan using his scanner and print through his printer. Because this is an Intranet application, compatibility is not an issue. I can ensure the user has all drivers installed. But the client insists that the application should be embedded inside the browser and not run in a native window. All client machines are Windows PC, but the client is flexible with browser choice.

I am thinking about writing an ActiveX control. But then I am not sure if I am using some 90s technology when better technologies might be available. Therefore, is there anything else I can look at? If I have to write ActiveX, can you point me to a good sample app to start with? I am very comfortable with C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .htc extensions on Html files. This puts the website in a different sandbox which allows for more access on client side functions (eg. execute commandline software which connects to a printer or scanner...)